# getting syntax error whle integrating sass files in reactJs with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, node-sass

Unexpected token (1:0) @import "./variables"; Getting this error using webpack
my webpack.config is like this module:

```
{ 
     rules: [ 
       { 
         test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/, 
         use: ['babel-loader'] 
       },
       {
          test: /\.scss$/, 
          use: [
           { loader: "style-loader" },
           { loader: "css-loader" },
           { loader: "sass-loader" }
          ]
       }
  ]
 }
```

Any one help me to sort the issue

Comment: what webpack version are you using ? also try changing current import statement to import "~./variables" or import "variables"  check if one of these works for you.

Comment: my web-pack version is 4.19.1  and i tried your style but it isn't working

Comment: `loader: "postcss-loader" ,// compiles Sass to CSS,
     options: {
             options: {}
           }` when I used this webpack isnt showing any error but  when I run my node then it's again showing same error
`D:\pro1\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:558
      throw err;
SyntaxError: D:/pro1/src/assets/scss/styles.scss: Unexpected token (3:0)
 @ import "variables";
 .page-dashboard {
  
    .metrics {`

Comment: i assume you have the style-loader installed?    How're you including your sass into your react application?

Answer (score -1):

Sass-loader seems to be incompatible with webpack 4.

You can use mini-css-extract-plugin which I use with webpack 4.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

People are facing this @import issue with webpack 4. Take a look at following thread.

https://gist.github.com/mburakerman/629783c16acf5e5f03de60528d3139af